# How to propertly configure certbot with autorenewal?

Tags: apache, docker

I'm learning `Docker` so I'm sorry if this question might sound silly. Anyway, my goal is create a `LAMP` container which handle all the databases in one place and also, I want to setup multiple virtual hosts for many sites. For each of this site I want use `certbot` to require a SSL certificate.

For doing so, I wrote the following `docker-compose.yaml`:

```
version: "3"

services:
  web:
    image: webdevops/php-apache:alpine-php7
    ports:
      - "80:80"
    volumes:
      - ./www:/app
      - ./php.ini:/opt/docker/etc/php/php.ini
      - ./sites-available:/opt/docker/etc/httpd/vhost.common.d
  
  db:
    image: mysql
    command: --default-authentication-plugin=mysql_native_password
    restart: always
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: root
    ports:
      - "3306:3306"

  phpmyadmin:
    image: phpmyadmin/phpmyadmin
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: root
    ports: 
      - "8088:80"

  certbot:
    image: webdevops/certbot
    volumes:
      - ./etc/letsencrypt:/etc/letsencrypt
```

in the first service, I'm declaring `Apache` as `web`, and I'm using the `alpine` image created by `webdevops`, [here the documentation](https://dockerfile.readthedocs.io/en/latest/content/DockerImages/dockerfiles/php-apache.html#customization). I bind the port `80`, so I can access to `Apache` externally without specify custom ports.
In the `volumes` section I added the `www` folder which contains the `php` scripts.

I also specified a custom `php.ini` to overwrite the default `php` settings. Then, as the last part of `volumes` I tried to mount all the virtual hosts which I created inside the folder `sites-available` in the `vhost.common.d` directory.

Then I have the `certbot` container as the last part of my `docker-compose` file, and I would like to do the following:

1. How can I request a certificate for my subdomain which I've actually stored inside sites-available folder that is mounted as volume of web container?
2. How can I set a cron job or something like a task that auto renew all the certificates?
3. How can I store in a volume the obtained certificates?

Comment: With apache `sites-available` are not `sites-enabled`.  **available** is the full list, **enabled** are active.  In the event you wish to disable any site without deleting their config.

Comment: `ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED`, I assume, is from your browser, which means that Apache either (a) did not start up properly, or that (b) the port is not opened/exposed properly.  Start by checking the apache logs (add any issues back to your original post).

Comment: did you try to reach it using http://localhost ?

Comment: See what the log says. `docker ps` `docker logs YOUR_CONTAINER_ID -f `. If you now call your domain and the log says something about it then the error is only in your vhost file. I have tested it your vhost file is loading but I think it is wrong. See in logs ;)

Comment: @GregorWedlich seems that building everything again has worked, infact now the subdomain correctly load the content of the virtual host. So now, I have updated the question since there is an open bounty, and I'm wondering if is possible run certbot along of this LAMP environment and set something like a cron job.

Comment: Please do not use irrelevant tags - this question is in no way related to PHP. Also, it could be better fitting on ServerFault

Comment: @sfarzoso I don't want to seem cheeky, but I think there are many guides here at Stackoverflow and also at the common search engines. Maybe they can explain it better.

Answer (score 1):

I will admit, docker at times is often a struggle to piece together all the appropriate parts, with that said, my answer will not be complete, but hopefully will get you a step closer.

The following will create a certificate (note the `--dry-run`, it is highly recommended you use this to do your testing, else you'll get throttled)

```
docker run -it --rm \
    -v /docker-volumes/etc/letsencrypt:/etc/letsencrypt \
    -v /docker-volumes/var/lib/letsencrypt:/var/lib/letsencrypt \
    -v /vol/to/the/web/root:/data/letsencrypt \
    certbot/certbot certonly \
    --noninteractive \
    --webroot --webroot-path=/data/letsencrypt \
    -d sub.domain.com \
    --dry-run
```

`-v /docker-volumes/etc/letsencrypt:/etc/letsencrypt`
this is needed to store the cert itself

`-v /docker-volumes/var/lib/letsencrypt:/var/lib/letsencrypt`
not required, but in-case you want to review log messages

`-v /vol/to/the/web/root:/data/letsencrypt`
you need to give access to your web root, so certbot can create the `.well-known` dir and do its checks, this one was a tricky one as you need to link/use the same location used for your web container web-root vol

`--noninteractive`
certbot will bypass asking you questions

`--webroot --webroot-path=/data/letsencrypt`
tell certbot where to find webroot (e.g. within its own container)

Although not in the command above, you can add the following to assist in creating the cert if prompted for email address, not sure if it is a requirement or not
`--email [email_address] --agree-tos --no-eff-email`

Things to keep in-mind:

- run certbot in `--dry-run` mode else, you will be throttled
- `certbot` will need http access to the host, your vhost declaration should not redirect or deny access to http requests at least to the `.well-known` directory
- you will need to add the appropriate SSL options in your vhost, i think certbot can do this automatically, but have not used this myself.
- you will then need to reload apache like so `/etc/init.d/apache2 reload`
- remove `-it` when/if you are running in cron
- explore wrapping the cert creation and renewal in a shell-script

While i know this is not "the answer", hopefully some of this helps.

Comment: Hi, this definitely helps! However, I don't understand a thing, forgive me the silly question but I'm still learning docker: did you install `certbot` on your system or are you using a certbot docker image? This is not clear to me, thanks for your help!

Comment: `docker run` is running the `certbot/certbot` image .. you can combine all the lines and run the above command manually to get a hang of it .. `docker run -it --rm -v /docker-volumes/etc/letsencrypt:/etc/letsencrypt -v /docker-volumes/var/lib/letsencrypt:/var/lib/letsencrypt -v /vol/to/the/web/root:/data/letsencrypt certbot/certbot certonly --noninteractive --webroot --webroot-path=/data/letsencrypt -d sub.domain.com --dry-run`, get used to running it manually, then you can automate